# Attaching the time-stamp to the name of a log file

Tags: logs, timestamps

I have a Makefile which I invoke using the following command:

```
    $ make analyze foo=History01
```

I have the following Makefile and I need to attached the timestamp to the name of the log file:

```
    analyze:
            cat $(foo) | perl tokenize.pl | flookup spanmorph.fst 2>&1 | tee -a $(foo)TIMESTAMP.log
```

Instead of TIMESTAMP I need the system timestamp (when the log file is created) with the format yyyyMMddHHmmss

I am a Ubuntu user by the way and I am not really experienced with Linux, I would be grateful for any answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [UUCA](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html) waning -- you mean `<$(foo) tokenize.pl`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of `TIMESTAMP`, put

```
$$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
```

in your one-liner recipe.

Comment: I have tried what you indicated me but the timestamp doesn't appear, ***although the log file is created*** but its name doesn't contain the timestamp as expected.

Comment: Might need some zero padding to force hhe output to always be teo digits, i.e. `%02m` pro `%m`, etc.

Comment: Because Make eats one dollar sign, you need `$$(date...)`.

Comment: @richardtk_1 - I've added #triplee's comment into #JosephR's answer.